# Ensuring Only Keepers Can Call My Contract's "performUpkeep" Function

Tags: chainlink

I have a keeper performUpKeep function that is mission critical that only a keeper can call and not some random third party to activate the contract sooner. It appears that the Chainlink keepers continually change so how can I ensure only the keepers call the contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you just need to validate that `checkUpKeep` is returning true, and you do some data validation on the input to make sure it can only do what you want it to. Per the [chainlink github](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/keeper/blob/master/contracts/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol):

> - @dev The input to this method should not be trusted, and the caller of the
>   * method should not even be restricted to any single registry. Anyone should
>   * be able call it, and the input should be validated, there is no guarantee
>   * that the data passed in is the performData returned from checkUpkeep. This
>   * could happen due to malicious keepers, racing keepers, or simply a state
>   * change while the performUpkeep transaction is waiting for confirmation.
>   * Always validate the data passed in.

### The below code is not advised to use

If you'd like to ignore this... (which you shouldn't) but you could add an `onlyKeepers` modifier to your `performUpkeep` function so only the Keepers registry can call your contract.

```js
    address public keepersRegistry = xxxxxx;
    modifier onlyKeepers() {
        require(msg.sender == keepersRegistry, "Ownable: caller is not keepers registry");
        _;
    }
```

And then wrap your function in that.

```js
function functionName() onlyKeepers {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer, as I'm not sure if it's correct.

The chainlink [KeeperCompatibleInterface](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/keeper/blob/master/contracts/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol) implementation specifies for the performUpkeep function :

```
    * @dev The input to this method should not be trusted, and the caller of the
    * method should not even be restricted to any single registry. Anyone should
    * be able call it, and the input should be validated, there is no guarantee
    * that the data passed in is the performData returned from checkUpkeep. This
    * could happen due to malicious keepers, racing keepers, or simply a state
    * change while the performUpkeep transaction is waiting for confirmation.
    * Always validate the data passed in.
```

Where the important bit is obviously :

```
 * @dev The input to this method should not be trusted, and the caller of the
 * method should not even be restricted to any single registry.
```

Given that you must implement a checkUpkeep function, you could simply secure yourself by checking the conditions of checkUpkeep again before calling the performUpkeep logic. If a third-party calls on your contract when an upkeep is required, just do it. If not, revert the transaction.

As specified [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/best-practices/#validation-of-trigger-conditions).

Comment: Wow, I hadn't seen this. Thank you so much for this answer. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you!